# Why does AWS Lambda uses older node version?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

It seems like [aws lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) uses older node version 0.10.36

Is there any reason to not to use newer versions of node or maybe even latest iojs compiler?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer is that 0.10.36 is the version you get from the EL6 EPEL repository with `yum install nodejs`.  You have to do extra work to get a newer version.

Comment: Yeah, screw performance and bug fixes, it's just easier to install 0.10.36. Thank you for answer